# I don't know where it went wrong in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]

I have created a 3 select option inputs based on 1st selection option it should populate the  2nd dropdown and based on 1st and 2nd selected option then it should populate the 3rd dropdown.

Unexpected token

```
const availableState = data.countries.find((c) => c.name === selectedCountry);
 const availableCities = availableState?.states?.find((s) => s.name === selectedState);
```

render method select options

```
<div>
        <label>Country</label>
        <select
          placeholder="Country"
          value={selectedCountry}
          onChange={(e) => setSelectedCountry(e.target.value)}
        >
          <option>--Choose Country--</option>
          {data.countries.map((value, key) => {
            return (
              <option value={value.name} key={key}>
                {value.name}
              </option>
            );
          })}
        </select>
      </div>

      <div>
        <label>State</label>
        <select
          placeholder="State"
          value={selectedState}
          onChange={(e) => setSelectedState(e.target.value)}
        >
          <option>--Choose State--</option>
          {availableState?.states.map((e, key) => {
            return (
              <option value={e.name} key={key}>
                {e.name}
              </option>
            );
          })}
        </select>
      </div>

      <div>
        <label>City</label>
        <select
          placeholder="City"
          value={selectedCity}
          onChange={(e) => setSelectedCity(e.target.value)}
        >
          <option>--Choose City--</option>
          {availableCities?.cities.map((e, key) => {
            return (
              <option value={e.name} key={key}>
                {e}
              </option>
            );
          })}
        </select>
      </div>
```

Comment: Where is the unexpected token? I don't see any overt issues with the top snippet. Can you include the full error message (as text please) and any accompanying stacktrace in your question?

Comment: Drew Resse Yes  i have included an image please find out or error(unexpected token ) is coming in these two lines                                                                            const availableState = data.countries.find((c) => c.name === selectedCountry);
 const availableCities = availableState?.states?.find((s) => s.name === selectedState);

Comment: Can your code handle Optional Chaining? If you instead do `const availableCities = availableState && availableState.states && availableState.states.find((s) => s.name === selectedState);` does it work?

Comment: now this error comes                               `<option>--Choose State--</option>
> 341 |           {availableState?.states.map((e, key) => {
      |                           ^
  342 |             return (
  343 |               <option value={e.name} key={key}>
  344 |                 {e.name}`

Comment: I can't tell what that error is since you posted only code, but it is likely the same thing with the Optional Chaining. Seems your project isn't configured for ES2020 features. Try using guard clauses instead: `availableState && availableState.states.map(......`. Convert all your Optional Chaining usages to guard clause null checks. Eventually you'll want to look into updating your project to transpile into newer Javascript syntax so you can use these features.